# Java, Tomcat - Can you load a resource during run-time from the WEB-INF/lib directory?

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a Java project deployed on Tomcat 8. I'm not using any framework.

If, during run-time, I run something like:

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("xyz");
```

This works if "xyz" is a file located in the WEB-INF/classes directory; however, the above line returns 'null' if the file "xyz" is located in the WEB-INF/lib directory.

Is there any way for me to read files in the WEB-INF/lib directory during run-time using the 'getResourceAsStream()' method of the 'ClassLoader' class?

Comment: The answer is no. WEB-INF/lib is not in the classpath. It is supposed to contain jar files, that are in the classpath. Why don't you just put the file under WEB-INF/classes?

Comment: Thing is you cant access files from lib folder, put you file in some other location. 

alternate solution is you have to out absolute path of file.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer guys. I was just making sure. (Now I know a little bit more about how Tomcat works.)

Comment: @OmerHassan - you should add an answer to complete this question if no more opened questions.

Answer (score 0):

The answer, as I've learned from the comments, is that Classloader.getResourceAsStream() cannot read from the WEB-INF/lib folder in Tomcat.